# Secondary x-axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following data frame:

| PhiSize | CumVol | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11.40 | 0.08 | a |
| 11.15 | 0.15 | a |
| 10.91 | 0.21 | a |
| 10.68 | 0.25 | b |
| 10.44 | 0.29 | b |
| 10.20 | 0.32 | c |
| 9.95 | 0.38 | c |

What i want to plot is a line-plot that has a secondary axis like the one above:

[image: desired plot that has secondary axes]

So far i did

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(read_csv("file")

ggplot(aes(x = PhiSize, y = CumVol, color = Group ), data = df) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_reverse()
```

And got the following plot:
[image]

But when i add the last line:

```r
ggplot(aes(x = PhiSize, y = CumVol, color = Group ), data = df) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_reverse()+
  sec_axis(2^(-df$PhiSize),name = "new")
```

It throws:

> Error: Can't convert a double vector to function

I would like to get some help, please.

Comment: I think your syntax is a bit off. You need to put the `sec_axis` inside `scale_x_reverse` and you don't need to repeat the x variable, just specify the transformation. Check examples in the [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html)

Comment: Please read the documentation about using `sec_axis`! First, it needs to be used within `scale_*_continuous`, not on its own. Second, it often uses a `~`-based formula, where a `.` indicates the normal axis value and the rest of the formula is its transformation. *You must have a mathematic transformation*, period; there is no pairing or use of another variable in the array (though that is a requested feature, unlikely to be allowed).

Comment: (Really, `scale_*_*` ... my comment that it should be `scale_*_continuous` is based on the current case that it only works with continuous data, discrete is a feature-request still to be fulfilled. However, since you have `scale_x_reverse`, it belongs in there, as I've demonstrated in my answer.)

Comment: @r2evans actually, I wasn't able to implement the right code. I was lost trying to understand the way to use "~ ." in a correct way.
But thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
ggplot(aes(x = PhiSize, y = CumVol, color = Group ), data = df) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_reverse(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 2^(-.),
    breaks = scales::log_breaks(n = 10),
    labels = scales::label_number()))
```

[image]